# localStorage cleared on app restart with Cordova 1.7 and iOS 5.1.1

Tags: ios, cordova, local-storage

From my extensive reading, the iOS 5.1 localStorage/WebSQL behavior change that Apple instituted has been fully rolled into Cordova 1.6.0.
However, while running on my (new) application on Cordova 1.7.0 and iOS 5.1.1, I am still seeing ugly, incorrect behavior.

I use window.localStorage to store and retrieve data.  E.g.
  window.localStorage.getItem("activeFormId")
  window.localStorage.setItem("activeFormId", formId);
These work flawlessly during the same session of the Cordova-based app.  If I background the app with the main iOS button then resume, that usually works as well.

However, the moment I kill the application (double-tap, long-press, tap the red circle) and relaunch, all localStorage data is lost.  I have verified this with jsconsole.com as well.

Are there additional steps I need to take to ensure the persistence bug fixes are working?  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using 1.7 - I had a similar issue and once I upgraded to 1.7 everything worked like it used to.

Try using localStorage vs window.localStorage syntax.

Also set what ever you're trying to call as a global variable...

```
var globalVar;

function onDeviceReady(){
  globalVar = localStorage.getItem('something');
}
```

Comment: Drew, per the details of the question, I am already using 1.7.

Comment: sorry i thought i read as you were using 1.6. try using the LS without window. syntax and just localStorage.getItem() - localStorage.setItem()...

Comment: That... surprisingly... worked!  However, it leads to another issue, where the session has been cleared out and so AJAX calls fails. To be addressed in another question or Cordova bug report.

Comment: nice! Okay set what ever variable it is that you're calling as a global variable in your on device ready function. Modified my answer

Comment: @JasonShah, FYI `localStorage` is PhoneGap's implementation of the browser's window.localStorage behind the scenes. unlike `window.localStorage`, PhoneGap's implementation persists when the app closes

Comment: Does any one know if this cordova localstorage gets not removed when updating the application too ?

Comment: @SeB.Fr it will persist on app update. the only time it goes away is on app delete or you manually remove it.

Comment: On iOS 5.0 and later the system may delete the localstorage. The file is saved at <App-Home>/Library/Caches/ and this directory is not persistent: "...the system may delete the Caches directory on rare occasions when the system is very low on disk space. This will never occur while an app is running. However, you should be aware that iTunes restore is not necessarily the only condition under which the Caches directory can be erased." https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html