# LocalStorage not persistent with Phonegap

Tags: android, cordova, local-storage

I'd like to keep data on user's mobile with localStorage. My app is build with phonegap.

```
function check_connection()
{
    var id = window.localStorage.getItem("id");
    if(id != null)
        // some code
    console.log(id);
}
```

When I do this code after `window.localStorage.setItem("id", "value");`, I get "value", but if I exit the application and run it again, I get "null".

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", main, true);
function main()
{
    check_connection();
}
```

The exit seems to clear the localStorage object.

Any idea ?

EDIT : The data is persistent when I quit the app by pressing back button, but when I kill the app from recent apps, the data is cleared. What is the problem ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10881059/localstorage-cleared-on-app-restart-with-cordova-1-7-and-ios-5-1-1  Try this

Comment: It's not persistent too :s

Comment: this question has a working answer that doesn't require using the database http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16240613/localstorage-store-not-persisting-on-android-phone-when-app-stops-using-sencha-t

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you calling somewhere window.localStorage.clear();?

Comment: Yes, I tried to remove these lines but it's not working too. Look at my edit

Comment: When the app is killed via the task manager, the javascript process is subsequently killed. When javascript is killed it does not fire an event that you can act on.

Comment: So is there a solution ? Or I mustn't use localstorage ?

Comment: You can save your data in database, it will solve your problem

Comment: Uning this : http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.6.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#Database ?
And is the database on the phone ?

Comment: Yes, This is, U can use this reference
In phonegap, transactions are so simple