# Complete data loss Ionic / Cordova LocalStorage and Websql iOS 8.4.1

Tags: javascript, sqlite, cordova, ionic-framework

My app is build with Ionic / Cordova 5.0.0 - Using SQLite (PouchDB) for the majority of the data, and localStorage for preferences and what not.

Out of 300+ iOS users, I've had 4 users report complete data loss. The app simply reset to the original state as if Localstorage and the Websql data was blown out completely. All of these users are on iOS and running 8.4.*

I've tried to reproduce the problem by manually deleting all localstorage, which resets the app as expected, but the SQLite data remains. I simply cannot figure out anyway to reproduce this, let alone figure out how it could be happening.

Note: I haven't had any reports from Android.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you backup user's data on a server or it only exists on their device?

Comment: Backup and syncing is available.

Comment: Any luck figuring this out yet? I'm experiencing similar issues with an app built on Cordova 5+ using Web SQL.

Comment: @thisisbrians  After talking with a few users that this happened to, I now suspect it happens when an Apple device is running low on space. Rumor has it, Apple will just blow away certain types of files and data to help free up space.  Which is why Apple recommends that any local data should be able to be re-created by the app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I've recently discovered, iOS wipes localstorage when the device is low on space.